# MitM socket connection for testing?

Tags: python, sockets

I'm trying to establish a mitm connection between me and a server which does some strange disconnecting and re-connecting sockets to begin comunnication succesfully. The case is I know how to accomplish it in vb using socket events, but can't get to it with Python. In vb, the code would be:

```vb
Private Sub SckClient_ConnectionRequest(ByVal requestID As Long)
  sckserver.Connect 'Conecta
  sckclient.Close 'Close Old Connection for Client

  Do Until sckserver.State = sckConnected 'Loop till Server is Connected
    DoEvents 'Wait
  Loop 'Loop

  sckclient.Close 'Close Old Connection
  sckclient.Accept requestID 'Accept Connection
End Sub


Private Sub SckClient_Close()
  sckclient.Close 
  sckclient.Listen
  sckserver.Close 
End Sub


Private Sub SckServer_Close()
  sckclient.Close 'Connection Close
  sckclient.Listen 'Wait for Connection
  sckserver.Close 'Close Connection
End Sub
```

The problem is Python seems to make socket objects disposable after `close()` and `shutdown()` methods, and has no simple `disconnect()` as far as i have seen, and I have not found any way to retrieve a socket state so as to mimic vb `close()` event. Btw, I've already tried multithreading, 1 thread to connect, another to wait for I/O data with select and another to loop the connection creating new socket objects, as existing can't be just disconnected, and reconnecting while there has been no data received.

Any ideas?